# During Nuclear fusion why Atomic mass of β becomes zero?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I would like to know during Nuclear fusion how/why Atomic mass of β becomes zero. For example: two Protons fuse to form a deuterium nucleus. Please see the attachment.

Thanks[image]

Comment: A $\beta$ particle is an electron (or in this case a positron), which is 2000 times lighter than a neutron or proton. Thus its mass can be neglected.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): in your equation the term $_2^0\beta$ has charge number $+2$, but the positron has charge $+1$. As written, your relation suggests incorrectly that charge is not conserved.

Answer (score 1):

The superscript is not mass, it is the *mass number* $A$ (i.e. the number of nucleons). It is is sometime called the "atomic mass", but that should be understood as a shorthand for "atomic mass number".

A positraon, being a fundamental particle in its own right, has zero nucleons and as such has a mass number of zero.

The notation used there is problematic, however, because a positron does not have a $Z$ of 2. Finally kudos to [Bill N](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/63690/bill-n) for noting that the neutrino has been left out of the final state (though to be fair it generally is in elementary treatments).

---

Aside directed toward the comments on the question: the positron mass is not negligible as it is about 20% of the energy liberated by the fusion.